# Complex string matching with LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wildcard

We are using LINQ to EF to develop a solution.

In my LINQ query I would like

```
string toMatch = "Matt Cool";

newString = toMatch.Replace(" ", "% ") + "%"; 

// So here newString is 'Matt% Cool%'

/*Now in my datasource, there is no 'Matt Cool', there's 'Matthew Coolguy'.
I would like this query to return that result. 
I would expect this behavior with the 
wildcard. It doesn't work*/

var results = from a in mycontainer.users
              where a.fullname.equals(newString)
              select a.fullname;
```

I tried "*" as a wildcard and a regex solution, to no avail -- Are there any other options?

Comment: I think you can replace  the first part of your code with 
newString = toMatch.Replace(" ", "% ") + "%";

Comment: Yeah you're right, I thought mine was explicitly more obvious for some reason... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of using **Equals** try using **Contains** this should take your wild cards because internally LINQ uses **LIKE** when you use **Contains**

```
var results = from a in mycontainer.users
              where a.fullname.Contains(newString)
              select a.fullname;
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a great article that describes how to do it:
[Regex in entity framework](http://csharpquestions.com/entity-framework/regular-expressions-in-entity-framework)

Comment: It looks like there's a copy of the broken article on [this page](http://advanceddotnettechnologies.blogspot.com/2011/02/tutorial-databinding-from-entity.html).